# What are is the use of 'top' function in describe(include='all') in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Create a Dictionary of series
d = 
{'Name':pd.Series(['Tom','James','Ricky','Vin','Steve','Smith','Jack',
'Lee','David','Gasper','Betina','Andres']),
'Age':pd.Series([25,26,25,23,30,29,23,34,40,30,51,46]),   
'Rating':pd.Series([4.23,3.24,3.98,2.56,3.20,4.6,3.8,3.78,
2.98,4.80,4.10, 
3.65])
}
#Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df.describe(include='all'))
```

If run this code I got the following output:

```
      Name        Age     Rating

 count       12  12.000000  12.000000
 unique      12        NaN        NaN
 top     Betina        NaN        NaN
 freq         1        NaN        NaN
 mean       NaN  31.833333   3.743333
 std        NaN   9.232682   0.661628
 min        NaN  23.000000   2.560000
 25%        NaN  25.000000   3.230000
 50%        NaN  29.500000   3.790000
 75%        NaN  35.500000   4.132500
 max        NaN  51.000000   4.800000
```

When I run the code each time the top function is changing.
What is the purpose of top function in output, and how it will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > what is the purpose of top function in output, and how it will work?

If you execute:

```
df.Name.value_counts()
```

You will see the value of a person in the `Name` column and their counts. top gives the highest counted value of the categorical values.

Example:

```
d ={'Name':pd.Series(['Tom','Steve','Ricky','Vin','Steve','Smith','Jack',
'Lee','David','Gasper','Betina','Andres']),
'Age':pd.Series([25,26,25,23,30,29,23,34,40,30,51,46]),   
'Rating':pd.Series([4.23,3.24,3.98,2.56,3.20,4.6,3.8,3.78,
2.98,4.80,4.10, 
3.65])
}
#Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df.describe(include='all'))

        Name        Age     Rating
count      12  12.000000  12.000000
unique     11        NaN        NaN
top     Steve        NaN        NaN
freq        2        NaN        NaN
mean      NaN  31.833333   3.743333
std       NaN   9.232682   0.661628
min       NaN  23.000000   2.560000
25%       NaN  25.000000   3.230000
50%       NaN  29.500000   3.790000
75%       NaN  35.500000   4.132500
max       NaN  51.000000   4.800000

print(df.Name.value_counts())

Steve     2
Ricky     1
Tom       1
Andres    1
Jack      1
Smith     1
Lee       1
Betina    1
Vin       1
Gasper    1
David     1
```

Since `Name` count for `Steve` is highest, it comes in top.

Comment: And in OP example: `['Tom','James','Ricky','Vin','Steve','Smith','Jack',
'Lee','David','Gasper','Betina','Andres']` all `Name.value_counts` are `1`. That's why `top` is random. Am I correct?

Comment: @AlexYu its rendering same output everytime for me though, based on the same logic. :)

Comment: @AlexYu its giving same value, but when restart the kernel its giving different values .